# What is $\lim\limits_{z \to \pi/2} \tan^2(z) $ for $z \in \mathbb C$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I am trying to evaluate the following limit ($z \in \mathbb C$):

$$\lim\limits_{z \to \pi/2} \tan^2(z) $$

I get the following solution:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \pi/2} \tan^2(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to \pi/2} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)} = \lim\limits_{x \to \pi/2} \frac{1 - \cos^2(x)}{1-\sin^2(x)} = \infty$$

whereas:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \pi/2} \tan^2(ix) = \lim\limits_{x \to \pi/2} \frac{\sin^2(ix)}{\cos^2(ix)} = \lim\limits_{x \to \pi/2} \frac{(\frac{1}{2i}(e^{-x} + e^{x}))^2}{(\frac{1}{2}(e^{-x} - e^{x}))^2} = \lim\limits_{x \to \pi/2} \frac{-(e^{-x} + e^{x})^2}{(e^{-x} - e^{x})^2} < \infty$$

Thus, I conclude the limit is undefined. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not correct.
$$\lim_{x\to\pi/2} \tan^2(ix)$$
has no bearing on the actual question. In that limit, you are approaching an argument of $i\pi/2$. You probably meant to consider
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\tan^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+ix\right)$$
which is infinite.

Comment: All'right - I see. So, if the limit is $\infty$, the function $\tan^2(z)$ has a pole at $z = \pi/2$. Now, how do I determine the order of that pole?

Comment: We have
$$
\lim_{z\to\pi/2}|\tan^2z|=\lim_{\xi\to0}|\tan^2(\pi/2+\xi)|=\lim_{\xi\to0}|\cot^2\xi|=\infty,
$$
and
$$
\lim_{z\to \pi/2}(z-\pi/2)^2\tan^2z=\lim_{\xi\to}\xi^2\tan^2(\pi/2+\xi)=\lim_{\xi\to0}\Big(\frac{\xi}{\sin\xi}\Big)^2\cos\xi=1,
$$
i.e. $z=\pi/2$ is a second order pole.

Comment: So, what your saying is, that the pole is of second order because this limit exists if we multiply $\tan^2(z)$ with $(z-\pi/2)^2$, right (the value of the limit doesn't matter, as long as it is defined and $< \infty$)?

Comment: Yes, and 2 is the smallest integer $k$ for which $\lim_{z \to \pi/2}(z-\pi/2)^k\tan^2z$ exists.

Comment: @Mercy All'right - thank you very much!